# How should I correct in the sintaxis of URLExecute

Tags: internet

- I usually perform a call to a APi with the next line:

  URLFetch["https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.\
          json?resources=search", 
              "Method" -> "GET",
              "Headers" -> { "Authorization" -> "Bearer " <> $token}
            ]

$token is my private token. And call's outcome is:

```
    "{\"rate_limit_context\":{\"application\":\"ZIfS6A0hLFFGn0rTK8AA\"},\"\
resources\":{\"search\":{\"\\/search\\/tweets\":{\"limit\":450,\"\
remaining\":441,\"reset\":1417461650}}}}"
```

And It's right. If I want to use the new function in Mathematica 10 `URLExecute`, How should I do? I tried next line as documentation shows but it doesn't work.

```
URLExecute["https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.\
json?resources=search",
 {"Method" -> "GET", "Headers" -> "Authorization: Bearer "<>$token},
  "JSON"]
```

Out:

```
{"errors" -> {{"code" -> 215, 
"message" -> "Bad Authentication data"}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the same "Headers" spec as URLFetch?  There really isn't much difference between URLFetch and URLExecute.

Comment: Yes, I correct the code above, but it's the same. and yes, they seems pretty similar. :'(

Comment: Second parameter of `URLExecute` are GET/POST parameters. Your "Method" and "Headers" should be options of `URLExecute`, not the second parameter.